# React - How to go back history and remove the forward histories?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-dom

In my app, the not-found page has a go back button.

The button triggers `history.goBack()`.

But after went back, user still can click the nav forward button to move back to the not-found page, which is not what I want.

I wish I could use `history.replace()` but I don't know where user comes from.

Is there a way to remove the forward history to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I think the proper way to do this is to prevent history from creating for this page?

Comment: Possibly you don't need to trigger history.goBack then?